# Maven "error in opening zip file"

Tags: java, maven, mockito

When mvn3 clean installing, I get this error:

> error reading
>   Users/user/.m2/repository/org/mockito/mockito-all/1.9.0/mockito-all-1.9.0.jar;
>   error in opening zip file

I've been looking through the answers to similar questions and it sounds like the standard solution is to remove the repo and re-clean install, which I have done a few times, as well as by hand downloading the jar and putting it into the 1.9.0 folder. This does NOT solve the problem.

Comment: Don't download the files by hand. That's one of the reasons to use Maven cause it will this work for you....

Comment: I am still confused why downloading it by hand wouldn't solve this problem. If the only issue is that the repo is dead, shouldn't downloading it by hand from a repo that works solve the problem? Do I not understand something about what Maven does?

Comment: No, it should work by hand. But there may be hundreds of dependency that you'd have to download also!

Answer (score 3):

Please try with the command to purge local repository.
 **Example: mvn dependency:purge-local-repository** 
   **Reference url:**https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/purging-local-repository.html

Answer (score 1):

Referencing the dead repository com.google will still return a jar, but the jar will not be understood by Maven.

Comment: It looks like this is a dead topic that no one came back. I had this issue today and your solution worked like charm! Not even deleting the whole m2 folder and running install again did it. Thank you man: you saved me in my first day of a new job!